# How can I define a decreases for mutually recursive functions in Dafny?

Tags: dafny, mutual-recursion

In the "Draft Dafny Reference Manual"   4.0.2 it describes defining  decreases clauses for mutually recursive functions but where the variables decreasing in both functions are of the type `nat`. I have tried to do the same thing but it has not worked. One difference is that the variables are not of the same type.

```
datatype Trie = Trie(letters : map<char,Trie>, word : bool)

function  size(t:Trie) :(r:nat)
    decreases t 
  { 
      1 + sum_setT(t.letters.Values)
  }
function  sum_setT(xs: set<Trie>) : (z:nat) 
decreases xs
  {
    var working := xs; //Needed!
    if (|working| == 0) then 0
    else  (
        var x:Trie  :| x in working;
        var sofar:nat := sum_setT(working-{x});
        sofar + size(x)
    )   
  }
```

Any idea how to define the decreases clause much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If two functions (possibly the same function) call each other recursively, then each call needs to be shown to decrease the termination metric given by the `decreases` functions. More precisely, if on entry to a function `F`, the `decreases` clause of `F` evaluates to `X`, and when `F` calls function `G` at a time when `G`'s `decreases` clause evaluates to `Y`, then `X` must be shown to exceed `Y`.

The "exceeds" relation is a built-in well-founded order, but you have control over the `decreases` clauses that give rise to the values `X` and `Y`. In your example, the easiest way to define these is to use lexicographic tuples. In the "outer" function, `size`, use `t`. In the "inner" function, `sum_setT`, use `t, xs` for the same `t`. To get this to work out, you'll need to add `t` as a parameter to `sum_setT` as well.

In the call from `size` to `sum_setT`, `X` and `Y` are `t` and `t, t.letters.Values`, which is smaller because the built-in well-founded order in Dafny considers shorter `decreases` tuples to be larger.

In the recursive call of `sum_setT`, `X` and `Y` have the same first component (`t`) and the set is strictly smaller in `Y`.

In the call from `sum_setT` back to `size`, the value `x` is structurally included in `t`, so `t` exceeds `x` as required. For the verifier to know this fact (that is, for it to know that parameter `xs` has some relation to `t`), you'll need to add a precondition to `sum_setT`.

So, the final program is

```
datatype Trie = Trie(letters: map<char, Trie>, word: bool)

function size(t: Trie): nat
  decreases t
{ 
  1 + sum_setT(t, t.letters.Values)
}

function sum_setT(t: Trie, xs: set<Trie>): nat
  requires xs <= t.letters.Values
  decreases t, xs
{
  if |xs| == 0 then
    0
  else
    var x :| x in xs;
    var sofar := sum_setT(t, xs - {x});
    sofar + size(x)
}
```